# How to combined two separate chart into one chart Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I wrote this code for thinking of one chart with two lines. But it showed up with two separate charts. Any ideas?

**LA_Temp=df.plot(x="Years",y="LA_avgtemp Yr")
df.plot(x="Years", y="LA_MA 10 Yr")**

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
ax = df.plot(x="Years",y="LA_avgtemp Yr")
df.plot(x="Years", y="LA_MA 10 Yr",ax=ax)
```

If that doesn't work, you may have a non-standard matplotlib set-up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ax` parameter in pandas.dataframe.plot.

Use on the first df.plot to grab a handle on that axes:

```
ax = df.plot(x="Years",y="LA_avgtemp Yr")
```

then on subsequent plots use the ax parameter.

```
df.plot(x="Years", y="LA_MA 10 Yr", ax=ax)
```